# MethodInfo showing null when getMethod is invoked with parameters containing reference type

Tags: c#, reflection

```
 public abstract class DbAttribute : IComparable
 {
 }

public abstract bool GetString(DbAttribute attributeName, ref string attributeValue);

Assembly testAssembly = null;
Type attributeA = testAssembly.GetType("A.Core.Data.DbAttribute");   
Type elementA = testAssembly.GetType("A.Core.Data.DbElement");

MethodInfo mi = elementA.GetMethod("GetString", new Type[] { attributeA, typeof(System.String)});
```

`mi` is null event hough `elementA.getMethods()` show me the `GetString` method. I think i am doing something wrong with parameter `attributeA`.

If I use `typeof(System.Object)` instead of attributeA, still it returns null.

Please suggest how to use the `GetMethod` properly in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it caused by ref parameter

```
MethodInfo mi =ElementA.GetMethod("GetString",new Type[] { typeof(AttributeA)  ,typeof(System.String).MakeByRefType()});
```

Comment: typeof(AttributeA) doesn't work still. however makebyreftype was the answer. Cheers !! You made my day. Thanks feiyun0112